# Drupal 7: Hooks added after module is enabled are not called

Tags: drupal-7

I've noticed that if I added new hook to a module after the module has been enabled,
the new hooks are not called.

I am trying to add hook_node_view, to control view of a content type from my module,
I am using the base name of the content type I am addressing lesson_node_view

Can some please explain to me ? and how to solve this issue ??

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flush your cache, `module_implements` is cached. `admin/config/development/performance` has a Clear all caches button. See the [Suppress caching (for development)](http://drupal.org/node/797346) for a way to avoid this and other problems during development.

Comment: i wish i had found this answer earlier!

Answer (score 0):

When writing your *.module file make sure not to use "namespace".
The namespace cause hooks not to be recognized. 
A utility code however may use a namespace.